# Xampp windows error MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I have a problem with xampp, I hope someone can help me because I'm working on a wordpress site. When I start MySQL I obtain the following error:

```
    15:22:10  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
    15:22:10  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
    15:22:17  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
    15:22:17  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
```

This is a part of my mysql_error.log. I can't paste more because of characters limit:

```
 2020-05-13 15:22:11 18 [ERROR] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
            ': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 19 [ERROR] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
            ': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [ERROR] Failed to create a new master info file (file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002011@0020@005berror@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020sql@003a@0020unable@0020to@0020.info', errno 2)
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 18 [Note] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
            ': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002011@0020@005berror@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020sql@003a@0020unable@0020to@0020.info' failed
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 18 [ERROR] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
            ': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-05-13 14:55:25 11 [ERROR] Master 'Version: '10.4.11-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
            ': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.' to hash table
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 18 [Note] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
            ': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005bnote@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@0020thread@003a@0020star.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005bnote@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@0020thread@003a@0020star.info'
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 18 [Note] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
            ': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [ERROR] Failed to create a new master info file (file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005bnote@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@0020thread@003a@0020star.info', errno 2)
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005bnote@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@0020thread@003a@0020star.info' failed
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-05-13 14:55:25 10 [Note] Master 'Version: '10.4.11-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
            ': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306'' to hash table
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@00200@0020@005berror@005d@0020aborting@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@00200@0020@005berror@005d@0020aborting@000d.info'
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@00200@0020@005berror@005d@0020aborting@000d.info'
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ' to hash table
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Started replication for '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            '
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 21 [Note] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@00200@0020@005berror@005d@0020aborting@000d.000017' position: 4
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005berror@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@003a@0020fatal@0020erro.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005berror@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@003a@0020fatal@0020erro.info'
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 20 [ERROR] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 21 [ERROR] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [ERROR] Failed to create a new master info file (file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005berror@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@003a@0020fatal@0020erro.info', errno 2)
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 20 [Note] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d05@002d13@002014@003a55@003a25@002010@0020@005berror@005d@0020master@0020@0027version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e11@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@003a@0020fatal@0020erro.info' failed
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 20 [ERROR] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-05-13 14:55:25 10 [ERROR] Master 'Version: '10.4.11-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
            ': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting t' to hash table
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 20 [Note] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 0 [Warning] Reading of some Master_info entries failed
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 20 [Note] Master '2020-05-13 14:55:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            ': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
            2020-05-13 15:22:11 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```